# LinearLayout with blank space at the bottom

Tags: android, css, android-layout

I am using LinearLayout horizontal to load view from the adapter. Though I am using wrap_content and views within the layout are aligned to top. And there is a blank space below the linearLayout. Is this is a bug or what am I doing wrong. Please do check the attached [image: screenshot]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/recycler_selector">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/group_chat_photo" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/ListTitleTextStyle"
                android:id="@+id/group_name" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/group_name"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/num_of_group_users"
                style="@style/PresenceTextStyle"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/group_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/SubTitleTextStyle"
                android:layout_below="@id/group_name"
                android:id="@+id/group_members_presence"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dots_vertical_grey600_24dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/group_chat_options"
            android:id="@+id/group_chat_options"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong in the adapter? Don't think your problem is in the LinearLayout. Is it a RecyclerView adapter?

Comment: Can you please post your adapter class?

Comment: @Contextioner see my answer below. I have redesigned your xml. For output see attached image. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `LinearLayout` attribute `android:layout_weight` to `RelativeLayout`.
I have redesigned your xml with `RelativeLayout`. See the attached image for output.

**Here is the working code. Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="82dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#455A64"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/group_chat_photo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/group_chat_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dots_vertical_grey600_24dp"
        android:contentDescription="group_chat_options" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/group_chat_photo"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/group_chat_options"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/group_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Americal AllStars"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/group_members_presence"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/group_name"
            android:text="Alucard, Client"
            android:textColor="#0788C9"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num_of_group_users"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/group_members_presence"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/group_members_presence"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="and 10 others"
            android:textColor="#0788C9"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help you~

Comment: @Contextioner If my answer seems useful please give an up vote. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This element is the main problem,

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/num_of_group_users"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toEndOf="@id/group_name"
  android:layout_toStartOf="@id/group_name"
  tools:text="10 users"
  android:padding="5dp" />
```

Since,  you are already using relative layout, there is no need to wrap this around linear layout. You can use single RelativeLayout as container. For example, following is just idea, you can change padding and margin as per your need.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/group_chat_photo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/group_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/group_chat_photo"
    tools:text="Some title" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_of_group_users"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/group_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/group_members_presence"
    tools:text="10 users" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/group_members_presence"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/group_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/group_chat_photo"
    tools:text="Presence" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/group_chat_options"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put the whole linear layout inside another layout (Relative or Linear) and set its width to "match_parent" and height to "wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is there where you are using layout_toStartOf and layout_toEndOf in one TextView(android:id="@+id/num_of_group_users") Remove one of them.